# Will a website on a different country publishing owned reviews from the original have any implication on SEO?

Tags: seo, seo-audit, negative-seo

So I have a website where I post affiliate product reviews etc. Let's say it's example.com. On this site, I post international product reviews which have worldwide shipping. Recently I bought example.in and I am planning to put only product reviews that ship to India only as .in is for India. Also, I will select the target country in the search console as India for this website. Now my question is since both these domains have a common name *example*, will they affect each other's SEO?

Comment: Check the guide of Google to duplicate content https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/guidelines/duplicate-content

Answer (score 1):

The answer is definitely Yes. Considering you are using same reviews and the only difference would be that the later has products that only ship to India.

It will help if you make sure that shipping destination becomes a **value proposition** on each website and why not, since content will be very similar and the reviews belong to you, go ahead and make a reference to each other using hreflang (only if websites are in different languages).

If they are not in different languages, alternatively you could create excerpt of each review or present the full review. On any case *always* link from xyz.in to xyz.com to refer to the original review, this is a technique similar to **content syndication**.

Note that Google wants to rank the original content first – even if it doesn’t always happen. Read about google guidelines on duplicate content [here](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/guidelines/duplicate-content)

Comment: Thanks a lot Raul. THese two websites will not share any product reviews. The .in website will only have local made products whereas .com will have international products. For example .in only has product reviews of amazon.in whereas .com will have amazon.com products , also I will make sure they don't have reviews of same product. So in this case does having similar name in domain affect each other?

Comment: @AshishBanerjee having a similar or exactly the same domain will not affect anything on both of your websites, think about it this way, currently there is more than 1000 top-level domains, .com, .website, .me, .info, .net you get the idea, so potentially you have another 998 domains sharing the same name. No problem at all having a repeated domain name!